# How to update a component built with Bit.dev in multiple projects?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, bit.dev

I have a project A and project B which both have installed (via npm) the same component X.

To use the updated component in both projects I have to manually go inside of each projects and execute yarn upgrade component-x.

We plan to have more than 30 projects consuming the same component and will be a completely nightmare go inside of each one and run yarn upgrade.

Is there a way where i can update this component in both projects after export with less effort?

If not so, how do I update this component that is installed across multiple projects more easily?

I'm using Bit Harmony version and NextJs as my framework and hosting them in Vercel.

Comment: I've wondered this myself. I don't think it's possible with yarn upgrade-interactive. What we have done is wrote a simple script that is `yarn upgradeAllBitDev` that manually forces the update to the latest for any package that starts with @bit. I might look into using the bit cli to see if there are updates.

Comment: Does `upgradeAllBitDev` updates across the projects? I have done something similar but it only upgrades our dependecies in the current project. What I am doing right now is trying to update them with dependabot but it always fail to authenticate.

Comment: unfortunately we haven't done this. We just do it manually in each project when they feel ready to upgrade to latest versions of our internal bit.dev components. I wish there was a way for yarn to detect that they need upgrading. I tried yarn upgrade-interactive with no luck.

Comment: Hello there! You must set your scope in Bit.dev to public then on your dependabot.yaml set the url of registry with value of 'https://node.bit.dev', the type with value of : npm-registry and the token containing the value of your .npmrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who is in need of some solution, we solve it by changing our scope in Bit.dev to public and then configuring the dependabot to lookup for our dependencies.

Basic example of functional dependabot.yml

```
version: 2
registries:
  bit-components:
    type: npm-registry
    url: https://node.bit.dev 
    token: ${{secrets.NPM_RC_TOKEN}}
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    registries:
      - bit-components
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```